# Mysql Database Row values fetching issue in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to fetch data present in database through select query. but something is wrong and data is properly fetched by this.I am not getting it. Let me know what i have done wrong.It would be helpful if you can tell me what need to be done here.I have accessed rows properly. but still it is not fetching the data.

```
<div class="c-cart-menu">
    <div class="c-cart-menu-title">
        <p class="c-cart-menu-float-l c-font-sbold">2 item(s)</p>
        <p class="c-cart-menu-float-r c-theme-font c-font-sbold">$79.00</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="c-cart-menu-items">
        <li>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST["view"]))
                {
                    include("connect.php");
                    if($_POST["view"] != '')
                        $update_query = "UPDATE notification SET noti_status=1 WHERE noti_status=0"; 

                    mysqli_query($connect, $update_query);
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM notification ORDER BY noti_id DESC LIMIT 5";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                    $output = '';
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                    {
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                            $output .= '

                            <div class="c-cart-menu-close">
                                <a href="#" class="c-theme-link"></a>
                            </div>
                            <img src="assets/base/img/content/shop2/12.jpg" />
                            <div class="c-cart-menu-content">
                                <p>
                                    '.$row["noti_header"].'
                                </p>

                                <a href="#" class="c-item-name c-font-sbold"><p>
                                    '.$row["noti_content"].'
                                </p></a>
                            </div>
                            </li>
                            ';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $output .= '<li><a href="#" class="c-font-sbold">No 
              Notification Found</a></li>';
                    }

                    $query_1 = "SELECT * FROM notification WHERE noti_status=0";
                    $result_1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query_1);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result_1);
                    $data = array(
                        'notification'   => $output,
                        'unseen_notification' => $count
                    );
                    echo json_encode($data);
                } 
            ?>
    </ul>

    <div class="c-cart-menu-footer">
        <a href="shop-cart.html" class="btn btn-md c-btn c-btn-square c-
          btn-grey-3 c-font-white c-font-bold c-center c-font-
          uppercase">View Cart</a>
        <a href="shop-checkout.html" class="btn btn-md c-btn c-btn-square 
         c-theme-btn c-font-white c-font-bold c-center c-font-
         uppercase">Checkout</a>
    </div>
</div>


Connect.php

  <?php 
 //connect.php;
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");
  if($connect === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
```

Comment: What kind of output you're getting ?

Comment: It is blank. It is not showing any errors as well. just blank

Comment: You never check for Errors (mysqli_error)

Comment: check the problem by adding `mysqli_error()` function...

Comment: I have added mysqli_error() function. I am not getting any errors and it is blank

Comment: can anybody help? i am not getting what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
Use a proper IDE like NetBeans,Sublime Text for writing php codes.These IDE will show the error ,warning indications.In your case,you missed one closing bracket.Use the below code.

<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM notification ORDER BY noti_id DESC LIMIT 5";
                                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                                $output = '';
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                      {
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                       {
                        $output .= '

                            <div class="c-cart-menu-close">
                                <a href="#" class="c-theme-link"></a>
                            </div>
                        <img src="assets/base/img/content/shop2/12.jpg" />
                            <div class="c-cart-menu-content">
                                <p>
                                    '.$row["noti_header"].'
                                </p>

                          <a href="#" class="c-item-name c-font-sbold"><p>
                                   '.$row["noti_content"].'
                                </p></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        ';
                         }}
                         else
                             {
              $output .= '<li><a href="#" class="c-font-sbold">No 
              Notification Found</a></li>';
                              }
               $query_1 = "SELECT * FROM notification WHERE noti_status=0";
                         $result_1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query_1);
                            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result_1);
                                 $data = array(
                                 'notification'   => $output,
                                 'unseen_notification' => $count
                                      );
                                 echo json_encode($data);

                       ?>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="c-cart-menu-footer">
         <a href="shop-cart.html" class="btn btn-md c-btn c-btn-square c-
          btn-grey-3 c-font-white c-font-bold c-center c-font-
          uppercase">View Cart</a>
         <a href="shop-checkout.html" class="btn btn-md c-btn c-btn-square 
         c-theme-btn c-font-white c-font-bold c-center c-font-
         uppercase">Checkout</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: i do use sublime text.

Comment: Try to use NetBeans,one of the best IDE for php code editing

Comment: There is nothing problem with sublime text i guess .

Comment: @Sinsil Mathew: Thanx but your solution didn't worked for me. :(

Comment: I tried with my own table and I am getting a result like this


\n assigned\n <\/p>\n\n

\n 237\n <\/p><\/a>\n <\/div>\n <\/li>\n \n\n
\n <\/a>\n <\/div>\n \n
\n

\n assigned\n <\/p>\n\n

\n 237\n <\/p><\/a>\n <\/div>\n <\/li>\n \n\n
\n <\/a>\n <\/div>\n \n
\n

\n assigned\n <\/p>\n\n

\n 237\n <\/p><\/a>\n <\/div>\n <\/li>\n \n\n
\n <\/a>\n <\/div>\n \n
\n

Please check your db connection

Comment: I dont have any errors. I have accessed right id's , sql table. why it is not working?

Comment: @SinsilMathew: yeah my db connections are fine

Comment: Can anybody please give me the solution?